# Which query plan is faster/better

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

I have two query plans for different queries that return the same results
I'm wondering if someone can tell me which one is "better", and why.

```
SELECT * 
FROM bids order by (select ranking from users where users.id = runner_id) DESC limit 1


"Limit  (cost=17.62..17.62 rows=1 width=568)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=17.62..17.62 rows=2 width=568)"
"        Sort Key: ((SubPlan 1))"
"        ->  Seq Scan on bids  (cost=0.00..17.61 rows=2 width=568)"
"              SubPlan 1"
"                ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=4)"
"                      Index Cond: (id = bids.runner_id)"
```

Second statement and plan:

```
SELECT  "bids".* 
FROM "bids" inner join users u on bids.runner_id=u.id  ORDER BY u.ranking DESC LIMIT 1

"Limit  (cost=17.64..17.64 rows=1 width=572)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=17.64..17.64 rows=2 width=572)"
"        Sort Key: u.ranking"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..17.63 rows=2 width=572)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on bids  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=568)"
"              ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on users u  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=8)"
"                    Index Cond: (id = bids.runner_id)"
```

Comment: use http://explain.depesz.com/ to find out more from your explain results

Comment: Run with `explain analyze` and you'll see which one is faster

Comment: Well they really both take the same amount of time.. such a small difference.

Comment: The second one has a nested loop but the time it takes is taken by the scan in the other plan.

Comment: It seems there is no real difference here.

Comment: As said by a_horse_with_no_name, use EXPLAIN ANALYZE. This will tell you what plan is the better one for your current situation. With different data in your tables, a different query plan might be better.

Comment: BTW. If there was an index on `ranking` then something like `select bids.* from bids, users where bids.runner_id = users.id and users.ranking = (select max(...)) limit 1` could be better.

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough in it to make any real difference. I would use the second one because the first one has a rather irregular syntax, which makes it more difficult to maintain. Slightly.

You might also try this:

```
select b.*
from   (select   id
        from     users
        order by ranking desc
        limit    1) u
join   bids                b on b.runner_id = u.id
limit  1
```

The last limit 1 might be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I think this query performance is better then second one

```
SELECT * 
FROM bids order by (select ranking from users where users.id = runner_id) DESC limit 1;
```

because see the explain analizer plane diff in 2nd one it is showing

> Nested Loop  (cost=0.28..17.63 rows=2 width=572)

in in respect to data structure always loop makes higher the complexity of the program output. and there are loads of other parameter see the

> width 
>   parameter for both cases.